# how to toggle fragments in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, slideshow, reveal.js

I have a line:

```
<div class="group2 big">starting as a<br>computer programmeur</div>
```

And initially all the text should be visible and normal. After "next" I want computer to be red. 2nd "next" computer should be normal again. 3rd "next" programmer should be red. I tried some combinations with nested fragments but that did not give the wanted behaviour. How can this be done?

```
<div class="group2 big">starting as a<br><span class="fragment highlight-red"><span class="fragment fade-in">computer</span></span> <span class="fragment highlight-red">programmeur</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`class="fragment highlight-current-red"` is what I was looking for.